# How to convert range to slice in rust?

Tags: rust

I want to create a slice of numbers within certain range in Rust. However, the following syntax does not seem to work, as the output is a slice of length 1, composed of a `Range` object.

```
let count = 10;
let slice = [0..count/2];
```

What's the proper way to create a slice in Rust from a range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot create a slice directly from a range (unless you know an upper bound to the number of elements at compile time, in which case you can use an array), you have to use `Vec`:

```rust
let vec = Vec::from_iter(0..count/2);
let slice = vec.as_slice();
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that neither slice nor range actually stores the elements, so `Vec` is needed to provide an actual storage place

Comment: @Finomnis How can I convert it then to a statically sized array?

Comment: @terett, that would be a different question actually.

Comment: @Netwave https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73192144/how-to-create-statically-sized-array-in-rust