# How to create statically sized array in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have the following array of constants in Rust:

```
const COUNTS: [usize; 5] = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16];
```

And the point is that I want to iterate over it like this:

```
for (i, count) in COUNTS.iter().enumerate() {
        const length: usize = *count/2;
        let indices: [usize; length] = Vec::from_iter(0..length).try_into().unwrap();
        let set: IndexSet<usize> = IndexSet::from(indices);
        ...
}
```

The point is that `from` method of `IndexSet` requires a statically sized array, i.e., `[T; N]`. What's the proper way here to create a statically sized array that includes the half of the values? Because the above code throws an error at `const length: usize = *count/2` that `count` is a non-constant.

Comment: statically sized means known at compile time, so you can just set it to the constant `2` in your case.
With const generics you can make this generic in newer versions of Rust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to statically add the array size:

```rust
let indices: [usize; 5] = Vec::from_iter(0..length).try_into().unwrap();
```

Which invalidates the purpouse of your code. That said, `IndexSet` implements [`FromIterator`](https://docs.rs/indexmap/latest/indexmap/set/struct.IndexSet.html#impl-FromIterator%3CT%3E):

```rust
use indexmap::IndexSet;
const COUNTS: [usize; 5] = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16];

fn main() {
    for (i, count) in COUNTS.iter().enumerate() {
        let length: usize = *count / 2;
        let set: IndexSet<usize> = IndexSet::from_iter(0..length);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=56eb20129d6367227477faa1cc941875)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `.collect` instead, which is a standard way to instantiate a collection (here `IndexSet`) from an other collection (here a range of numbers).

```rust
use indexmap::set::IndexSet;

const COUNTS: [usize; 5] = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16];

fn main() {
    for (i, count) in COUNTS.iter().copied().enumerate() {
        let length = count/2;
        let set = (0..length).collect::<IndexSet<_>>();
    }
}
```

See the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6e144b7f511f810c2ce1e0c36a130a0a).

Comment: Why did you use copied?

Comment: @Jaafar `COUNTS.iter()` is an iterator that returns elements of type `&usize`. Instead, it makes more sense (to me, at least) to, here, manipulate directly elements of type `usize`, since it's not more expensive. It's not related to the issue of the OP, it just seems more natural..

Comment: Got it thanks! Sure, I know it's unrelated.